# Why does ASP.NET ScriptManager partial update takes longer on Machine A than B on same LAN?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I want to find the root cause of an issue I am experiencing with my ASP.NET app.

Why will a partial update for the same action on the same web form take significantly longer time for one client than another on the same LAN?

It takes so long on one client that it exceeds the default `AsyncPostBackTimeout` value of 90 secs for the `ScriptManager` tag, os that there is no update on the page in the affected machine.

Slow Client Machine A : IE 8, Windows 7
Normal-Speed Client Machine B : IE 6, Win XP

Comment: Is one machine a SuperComputer and the other an i386? Are both builds the same configuration (Debug vs. Release)?

Comment: ie8 is slow, try to use on both google chrome, or mozilla and check again the speed.